# How to get data OUTSIDE a node.js query?

Tags: node.js

How do I get data from a query OUTSIDE the query in Node.JS? 
I can get results printed to the console INSIDE the function but I can't get the data OUTSIDE to use in other places in my application.

```
    this.getMyQuestion = function(id) {
        var query = connection.query('select * from questions where id = ' + connection.escape(id), function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            //console.log(result[0].question); //displays in console
            return(result[0].question);
        });

    }

var test = this.getMyQuestion(1);
console.log(test) //returns undefined.
```

Comment: did you try removing var query= and replaying to "return connection.query('....". The result is deep inside the callback. One dirty test to assign the value to global variable and test

Answer (score 1):

You're using an asynchronous function, so by the time you run the `console.log(test)` after calling your function, it hasn't finished running and hasn't returned anything yet.

That's what callbacks are for. You pass a callback to your function, and when it finishes execution, it calls that callback function instead of returning a value like it is now.

For example :

```
this.getMyQuestion = function(id, callback) {
    var query = connection.query('select * from questions where id = ' + connection.escape(id), function(err, result) {           
        callback(null, result[0].question);            
    });
}

this.getMyQuestion(1, function(err, question){
    // Do what you want
});
```

You can also [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to get data from async functions.